# Youtube API: Is there a way to refresh an access_token in the client side v3 api?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=XTHhXh1SlUNgvyWGwDk1EjXB&
refresh_token=1/6BMfW9j53gdGImsixUH6kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

The developer documentation lists a way to refresh an access_token on the back end. Is there a way to do this with the front end javascript calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the c[lient-side web applications flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#oauth2-tabs), which is appropriate if you're writing code in JavaScript that runs in the browser, then there's no way to get back a refresh token and periodically refresh it to get an access token. The accounts.google.com server doesn't support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), for one thing, so it's not possible to send the HTTP POST refresh request from your JavaScript.

What you can take advantage of is the `approval_prompt=auto` parameter behavior, which means that if a user has previously authorized access to your OAuth 2 client id for the same scopes, requesting a new access token can be done without any user intervention. So you can effectively get new access tokens indefinitely.

I'd highly recommend letting the [Google APIs JavaScript client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication) handle this for you. In addition to the samples in the docs, you can take a look at [this simple example](http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html) which shows how you can handle the OAuth 2 flow in a way that only requires initial authorization.

Comment: does it support long lived token on Client Side web applications now..?